# Three.js on object drag (mousemove+mousedown) collision with wall should stop the object from further drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

i am working on an app where user can drag and drop objects within a room, struggling to find a way where object drag should stop when object hits the wall (ray intersect ) code added to mousemove event is listed below, on wall collision with object it log "wall hit" successfully but object keeps on dragging, really appreciate your help in this regard.

```
    var proximityBox = renderer.itemSelected.parent.getObjectByName('proximityBox');
    var originPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
    originPoint.setFromMatrixPosition( proximityBox.matrixWorld );
    NelsonPlanner.renderer.scene.updateMatrixWorld();
            for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < proximityBox.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++){      
                    var localVertex = proximityBox.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
                    var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( proximityBox.matrixWorld );
                    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
                    vector.setFromMatrixPosition( proximityBox.matrixWorld );
                    var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( vector );
                    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
                    var wallsToCheck = [];
                    for( i in NelsonPlanner.renderer.scene.getObjectByName('walls').children ){
                        wallsToCheck.push(NelsonPlanner.renderer.scene.getObjectByName('walls').children[i].getObjectByName('3D').getObjectByName('wallCube'));
                    }   
                    var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( wallsToCheck );
            }
            if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ){
                console.log("wall hit");
            }
            else {

            }

}
```